# Get a whole column in a struct field in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct, directory

I have a struct in MATLAB with the size 46x6, the fields are:

```
name, folder, date, bytes, isdir, datenum
```

Now I want all 46 entries of `name`. However, the MATLAB function `getfield(structname, 'name')` only returns the first entry.

How can I get all elements of the struct?

Name holds strings

Comment: have you tried `structname(:).name`?

Comment: Is the struct array really `46x6` (with `6` fields),  or is it `46x1` (with `6` fields)?

Comment: sry for the late reply:

structname(:).name returns them all but seperated, so when i would do
tmp = structname(:).name it will only contain the first one

Comment: It is the first one @Luis Mendo

Comment: In that case, there are `276` entries of `name`, not `46`. Which `46` do you want?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I guess it is the second one then. I already posted an asnwer solving my problem, but I am not able to accept it, yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I had to convert the Struct to a cell, and then access it with round brackets

```
tmp = struct2cell(mystruct)
tmp(1,:)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the results as a cell array you can call `{structname(:).name}`.
To return an array you can call `[structname(:).name]`.

Comment: this did not work, it just concatenated the strings into one element

Comment: The array method just returns a single concatenated char, but the cell array method does work as intended if you're after that

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i = 1:numel(structname)
        name(i)= structname(i).name;
    end
```